# When using the Acumatica Test SDK, what do I need to point the tool/options screen to get the Test SDK to work?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am trying to get started with the Test SDK and I am having difficulties getting past the prerequisites. I'm using the most current SDK - Readme document and am on step 2 depicted on page 7. The image shows the Tools/options, but it is not clear what the local entry is pointing to.

The following bullet in the documentation depicts what the .csproj file should look like once finished. The documentation does not describe what needs to be done to get there. I’m looking for any help to get to that point.

[NuGet Package Manager Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6rNP.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see how you are stuck on this as the documentation is not very clear.  What you need to point to in NuGet Package sources is a folder that contains the .nupkg files in the TestSDK zip file. You will find these files in the packages folder in the unzipped TestSDK  package you downloaded from builds.acumatica.com. This is the same package you got the SDK - Readme document from. It looks like this.

[image: Inage 1]

Once you find it set the Source  in the options screen to that folder.

Now when you right-click on the dependencies in the visual studio project you will see the

[image: image 2]

Now set the Package source to Local. Assuming that's how you labeled it in options. Also make sure the Include prerelease is checked otherwise you will not see GeneratedWrappers.Acumatica.
Once done you can now install the packages.

[image: Inage 3]